# Running a test to see if numbers show up

Tags: javascript

Im following a YT video on how to make a calculator with JS, running a test to see if number show but when clicking on number buttons nothing shows on display, cant see whats wrong with the code. I am using VS Code and quite new to it, ive tried debugging but nothing shows up and if i do it returns a error of 8080 when i try to load on chrome.

```js
class calculator {
    constructor (previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
    this.clear ()
}
    
    clear () {
        this.currentOperand = ''
        this.previousOperand = ''
        this.operation = undefined
    }
    
    dalete () {
    
    }
    
    appendNumber (number) {
        this.currentOperand = number
    }

    chooseOperation (operation) {

    }

    compute () {

    }

    updateDisplay () {
        this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand
    }

}



const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
const equalsButton = document.querySelector ('[data-equals]')
const deleteButton = document.querySelector ('[data-delete]')
const allClearButton = document.querySelector ('[data-all-clear]')
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector ('[data-previous-operand]')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector ('[data-current-operand]')

const calculator = new calculator (previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
calculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
calculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Gotham Rounded, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;

}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #00aaff, #00ff6c);

}

.calculator-grid {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,100px);
    grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5,100px);
}

.calculator-grid > button {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid white;
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}

.calculator-grid > button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);

}

.span-two {
    grid-column: span 2;
}

.output {
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content:space-around ;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break:break-all ;
}

.output .previous-operand {
    color:rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    font-size: 1.5rem;

}

.output .current-operand {
    color:white;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="calculator-grid">
      <div class="output">
          <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand">
              <div data-current-operand class="current-operand">

              </div>

          </div>
      </div>
      <button data-all-clear class="span-two">AC</button>
      <button data-delete>DEL</button>
      <button data-operation>÷</button>
      <button data-number>1</button>
      <button data-number>2</button>
      <button data-number>3</button>
      <button data-operation>*</button>
      <button data-number>4</button>
      <button data-number>5</button>
      <button data-number>6</button>
      <button data-operation>+</button>
      <button data-number>7</button>
      <button data-number>8</button>
      <button data-number>9</button>
      <button data-operation>-</button>
      <button data-number>.</button>
      <button data-number>0</button>
      <button data-equals class="span-two">=</button>
```

Comment: Look at Chrome -> Developer Tools for errors

Answer (score 1):

In your script:

```
const mycalculator = new calculator (previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
   mycalculator.appendNumber(button.innerText)
   mycalculator.updateDisplay()
    })
})
```

You must change calculator variable name. This can't same the class name. Sorry for my bad English if i did any mistake in my sentences :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the JS in your web snippet, and rename the calculator variable, because it conflicts with the class name.

```js
class calculator {
    constructor (previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement) {
    this.previousOperandTextElement = previousOperandTextElement
    this.currentOperandTextElement = currentOperandTextElement
    this.clear ()
}
    
    clear () {
        this.currentOperand = ''
        this.previousOperand = ''
        this.operation = undefined
    }
    
    dalete () {
    
    }
    
    appendNumber (number) {
        this.currentOperand = number
    }

    chooseOperation (operation) {

    }

    compute () {

    }

    updateDisplay () {
        this.currentOperandTextElement.innerText = this.currentOperand
    }

}



const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-number]')
const operationButtons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-operation]')
const equalsButton = document.querySelector ('[data-equals]')
const deleteButton = document.querySelector ('[data-delete]')
const allClearButton = document.querySelector ('[data-all-clear]')
const previousOperandTextElement = document.querySelector ('[data-previous-operand]')
const currentOperandTextElement = document.querySelector ('[data-current-operand]')

const calc = new calculator (previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)

numberButtons.forEach(button => {
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
calc.appendNumber(button.innerText)
calc.updateDisplay()
    })
})
```

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Gotham Rounded, sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;

}

body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #00aaff, #00ff6c);

}

.calculator-grid {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(4,100px);
    grid-template-rows: minmax(120px, auto) repeat(5,100px);
}

.calculator-grid > button {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 2rem;
    border: 1px solid white;
    outline: none;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.75);
}

.calculator-grid > button:hover {
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);

}

.span-two {
    grid-column: span 2;
}

.output {
    grid-column: 1/-1;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.75);
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content:space-around ;
    flex-direction: column;
    padding: 10px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    word-break:break-all ;
}

.output .previous-operand {
    color:rgba(255,255,255,.75);
    font-size: 1.5rem;

}

.output .current-operand {
    color:white;
    font-size: 2.5rem;
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Calculator</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="calculator-grid">
      <div class="output">
          <div data-previous-operand class="previous-operand">
              <div data-current-operand class="current-operand">

              </div>

          </div>
      </div>
      <button data-all-clear class="span-two">AC</button>
      <button data-delete>DEL</button>
      <button data-operation>÷</button>
      <button data-number>1</button>
      <button data-number>2</button>
      <button data-number>3</button>
      <button data-operation>*</button>
      <button data-number>4</button>
      <button data-number>5</button>
      <button data-number>6</button>
      <button data-operation>+</button>
      <button data-number>7</button>
      <button data-number>8</button>
      <button data-number>9</button>
      <button data-operation>-</button>
      <button data-number>.</button>
      <button data-number>0</button>
      <button data-equals class="span-two">=</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bug is at your JavaScript code because you are using the same variable name for two different things (the *instance* of `calculator` and the `calculator` *class*) when you are doing:

```
const calculator = new calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)
```

The best solution is to change the name of your class, as it is a well practice to name the classes with the first letter in Capital. This is at your first line of code.

```
class Calculator {
...
```

Once you've done it, you should update the line where you are instantiating it in order to call it by its new name:

```
const calculator = new Calculator(previousOperandTextElement, currentOperandTextElement)
```

Notice how we only update the *Calculator* on the right side of the `new` word, as that is where the class name goes. The *calculator* word that is in the left side of the equal sign is the name of the variable, which should never be the same.